# Why is "being" used in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Please take a look at this sentence

> Linking verbs show a relationship between the subject and a noun or adverb **being** linked to it.

I want to understand the word **being**. I think it is not passive voice, because then there should be any "be" form (is, am, are) before it.

And I think without "being" the sentence is still correct.

> Linking verbs show a relationship between the subject and a noun or adverb  linked to it.

Can someone please explain why and in which context **being** is being used here?

Comment: Btw this sentence was used in this video http://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-linking-verbs/3639275.html at 0:42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to your first instinct, it may indeed be a passive construction inside a relative clause:

> Linking verbs show a relationship between the subject and a noun or adverb **that is being linked to it**.

There you have your form of *be*. Now this relative clause is shortened to a participle clause:

> Linking verbs show a relationship between the subject and a noun or adverb **<s>that is</s> being linked to it**.

Comment: Maybe you are right.But Why do we need to use "being" here? . Doesn't "that is linked" is more appropriate here.

Comment: @beginner - You certainly could say "that is linked" instead.  The phrasing with "being linked" emphasizes the *action* rather than the *state*, though.

Comment: Yeah "linked" feels more general(for always). "being linked" seems like we are using it for current scenario.  Thanks, I think i got it.